# Javascript for loop, my code isn't working, I want to add even numbers

Tags: javascript

I'd like to add even numbers using a for loop:

```
var x = "";
i = 10;

for (i <= 50) {
  if (!(i / 2 == 0)) {
    x + i;
  }
}
alert(x);
```

Comment: You need to use the modulo operator (`%`) which gives the reminder, not division operator (`/`) which gives the quotient.

Comment: This isn't even the correct syntax of a `for` loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for